# Scaling/Zooming Canvas in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am extremely new to FabricJS and I have run into something I am not too sure how to fix. I've been working on it for hours, so hopefully a fresh set of eyes can quickly spot the issues.

I am trying to scale a canvas element (after loading an image - lets say `1920x1080`) and I can zoom it with a slider.

Below is my implementation of this method:

```
function zoomCanvas(scale) {
    canvas.setZoom(scale);
    canvas.setWidth(editor.backgroundImage.getWidth() * canvas.getZoom());
    canvas.setHeight(editor.backgroundImage.getHeight() * canvas.getZoom());
}
```

and I call it in my `canvas.setBackgroundImage` function like so:

```
var canvasParent = canvas.getElement().parentElement.parentElement;
zoomCanvas((canvasParent.offsetWidth / canvas.backgroundImage.getWidth()) - 0.05);
```

This actually works exactly how I want it. It scales a bigger image down to the parent's width (and a little extra for padding - not sure if this is a good way); however, I am getting a slight issue on the bottom - and sometimes the right side - of my canvas/image. Apparently they are not getting scaled perfectly with one another and i get something like this:

[image]

I have tried rounding the decimal places, but that's no use and I am not sure what to do about it.

**Update:** Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xxqatt96/1/) of the issue. Scale the window up and sideways till you see a red line appear on the bottom (on mine it will appear either on the right or bottom).

**UPDATE 2:** I think I figured out the issue. I was zoomed into my browser 110% and Chrome was having some wierd rendering effects with the Canvas elements generated by fabric. However, I would not like this to happen when the browser is zoomed. Is this a bug in my CSS or a bug in Chrome? I am still getting the issue, but it is less frequent. Sometimes the lower-canvas is taller than the upper one in some cases.

Comment: would be helpful to have a js-fiddle here.

Comment: @AntonHarald you are correct. Give me a few moment to throw one together.

Comment: @AntonHarald Update: please check my secondary Update. I am sorry, I've been at it for WAY to long tonight. However, is this a bug in Chrome or in my CSS? I am however still seeing the issue slightly, just not as frequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a fresh look at all my code and doing some extensive testing, I found out that this is particularly an issue with FlexBox and **NOT** fabricjs.

In my code, I was trying to center vertically the Canvas in a div and flexbox was causing these weird issues. For more information, look at the JSFIDDLE and remove flexbox from the CSS.